# Race condition causing assets to load from wrong location in Electron when launched with Playwright

Tags: webpack, electron, playwright, webpack-style-loader

I have an electron app I am trying to add playwright tests to, and when I launch it using the playwright `_electron.launch()`, I have some SVG files that are used in my CSS trying to load from the `node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar` file, instead of from the Webpack `/build` directory. Launching it manually from the command line works fine, without rebuilding or anything.

[image: showing all files loading properly on the left, and on the right side SVG files try to load from electron.asar inside node_modules folder]

**Any ideas what could cause this?**

When I inspect the icon-load element in devtools element tab, the URL shows up like so:

```css
.icon-load {
    background: url(file:///F:/Programming/REDACTED/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/renderer/287f560038de84fa9ced.svg);
}
```

So far I have tried verifying body.baseURI as well as a few different options on `_electron.launch()`.

Devtools console session:

```js
window.$("body").baseURI
"file:///F:/Programming/REDACTED/build/"
```

launch-electron.js:

```js
// Launch Electron app.
const electronApp = await electron.launch({
  args: ["."],
  //cwd: "F:\\Programming\\REDACTED", // no change
  //bypassCSP: true, // no change
});
```

**Update 2:** Refreshing the page causes the SVG files to load from the correct location!! We appear to have a race condition with some kind of context switching in the electron launch. I'll add a snippet of my Webpack config again:

```js
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/renderer",
  entry: "./App.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "bundle.[fullhash].js",
  },
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
    children: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /App\.js$/i,
        loader: "expose-loader",
        options: {
          exposes: {
            globalName: "FF",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"], // disabling URL loading in CSS loader makes app load but without CSS images
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|ico|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Given what I have found a simple work-around for this would be to trigger a page refresh after the application loads initially.

Comment: Not sure that I want to do this, but switching to an `asset/inline` would obviously fix this problem too, since the SVG files would become embedded in the CSS.

Comment: I tried recreating this using electron-playwright-example and wasn't able to reproduce the problem! I'm still not sure what the culprit here is, although it looks like the example code may be running the fully packaged app..